# Python and HTML '% Operator'

Tags: python, html, css

I'm trying to get some HTML to work with my python code.
I've got this for one of my CSS codes.

```
#footerBar {
height: 40px;
background: red;
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
width: 100%;
z-index: -1;
}
```

However, when I try to access the page, I get the following error.

```
File "projv2.py", line 151, in welcome
</form>""" %(retrievedFullName, retrievedUserName,)
ValueError: unsupported format character ';' (0x3b) at index 1118
```

I think it's messing with the `%` since I do use that elsewhere in the HTML.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How are you "accessing" that page?

Comment: OK, have you tested what happens if you remove the `%` (replacing it by `px` or whatever). Does the error go away?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you want to use `%` formatting operator, you need to escape your `%` characters.

So your css should read:

```
#footerBar {
height: 40px;
background: red;
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
width: 100%%;
z-index: -1;
}
```

instead.

It's preferrable to use the string's [`.format()`](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#formatstrings) method instead as it is the preferable way. See [PEP 3101](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/) for rationale.

So instead of

```
...""" % (retrievedFullName, retrievedUserName,)
```

do

```
...""".format(retrievedFullName, retrievedUserName)
```

and change the `%s`'s in your string to `{0}` and `{1}`. Of course you need to escape your `{}`'s in this case, too.

Comment: Your answer is technically correct, which as we all know is the best kind of correct.

Comment: (+1'd now that you have a thorough discussion of escaping in format strings =])

Comment: @Kimvais in my code `.format` working with `%s` so *should I need to change `%s` to `{}`?*

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan no need to do it _for just the changes sake_, but if/when you DO need to make changes to it, might as well switch over to `.format()`